# Getting String from a Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently trying to capture the image URL within this Javascript call below, I'm struggling to get my head around the code.

```
<a href="javascript:fnChangeImage('.ItemImage.Main','http://www.forever21.com/images/5_detail_750/00185472-01.jpg');">
```

I have the following code fetching the title, price etc perfectly but I'm not too sure how to grab something from a javascript call.

```
var result = {
    productName: $(".pdp_title .item_name_p").text().trim(),
    description: $(".d_content span").text().trim(),
    price: $(".pdp_title .price_p").text(),
    imageUrls: []
};
```

Comment: What does fnChangeImage do?

Comment: @mplungjan I think he doesn't care, it seems like he is trying to scrape some data and he is interested in the image url passed to the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a one liner

```
var imageUrl = /.*,'(.+)'/.exec($("a[href^='javascript:fnChangeImage']").attr("href"))[1];
```

---

**How it works**

1. Select the dom element that is an anchor link and it's href starts
   with `javascript:fnChangeImage`
2. Apply regex pattern `/.*,'(.+)'/`
   on the selected element href attribute
3. The image url is captured in the first matching regex group.